# Разделить текст, сохраняя разделители

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

У меня 2 варианта данных:

```
text1 = 'здравствуйте убрать из счета позицию 1 добавить 2 убрать 3. добавить 4 жду исправленный счет'

text2 = 'здравствуйте из счета позицию 1 убрать 2 добавить   3. убрать 4 добавить жду исправленный счет'
```

Вывод должен быть такой:

```
для первого случая:

['здравствуйте ',
 'убрать из счета позицию 1 ',
 'добавить 2 ',
 'убрать 3. ',
 'добавить 4 жду исправленный счет']

для второго:

['здравствуйте из счета позицию 1 убрать ',
 '2 добавить ',
 '3. убрать ',
 '4 добавить',
 'жду исправленный счет']
```

разделителями являются слова

```
patterns = 'убрать|удалить|добавить|прибавить|изменить'
```

Comment: Вы уверены, что ответ внизу решает вашу задачу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Могу предложить такой вариант: после каждого уникального слова - разделителя вставить некий неиспользуемый в тексте символ или последовательность символов, чтобы слово попало, а этот символ или последовательность - нет.
Если список разделителей будет меняться динамически, то лучше, конечно, в цикле, а не руками, делать replace.

```py
text1 = 'здравствуйте убрать из счета позицию 1 добавить 2 убрать 3. добавить 4 жду исправленный счет'
delemiters = ['убрать', 'удалить', 'добавить', 'прибавить', 'изменить']
for d in delemiters:
    text1 = text1.replace(d, f'**{d}')

arr = text1.split('**')
```

Comment: В [результате имеем](https://ideone.com/xEtwW3) `['здравствуйте убрать', ' из счета позицию 1 добавить', ' 2 убрать', ' 3. добавить', ' 4 жду исправленный счет']`. Разве это совпадает с желаемым результатом?

Comment: Действительно, невнимательно глянул. Значит, разделительный символ нужно ставить перед разделительным словом, а не за ним. Поправил код.

Comment: По-моему, лучше не стало, `['здравствуйте ', 'убрать из счета позицию 1 добавить', ' 2 ', 'убрать 3. добавить', ' 4 жду исправленный счет']`